# Hide icon spotlight in El Capitan

Tags: macos, console, osx-elcapitan

Mac os x El Capitan

I want to hide the spotlight icon.
Enter the command:

```
sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search
```

In response to receiving this:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search: Operation not permitted
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Check this answers: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151586/how-do-i-hide-the-spotlight-icon-on-yosemite-but-keep-the-spotlight-functionali

Answer (score 28):

Not sure about the other answers, because `/System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle` doesn't seem to exist here.

However, if you're using [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/), you can still remove the Spotlight icon (while keeping Spotlight search in tact) by temporarily disabling System Integrity Protection.

1. Reboot into Recovery Mode (hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during boot)
2. Utilities > Terminal
3. `csrutil disable`
4. Reboot
5. Start Bartender. It'll ask to install some stuff, now that SIP is off
6. Hide Spotlight, which can now be found in Bartender's menu items list
7. Reboot into Recovery Mode and re-enable SIP: `csrutil enable`
8. Reboot

After you've re-enabled SIP, Bartender will keep hiding the icon.

Comment: Bartender is great

Comment: Wait, What? I need to go in safe mode and restart and stuff, for Bartender to actually work?

Comment: Works like a charm!  This approach requires the minimum effort, and makes no real change to the OS, no risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually also just start in recover mode (cmd + r) and type the command into the terminal. this way you achieve to hide the spotlight icon but don't have to diable sip.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, `Search.bundle` doesn't exist in the recovery environment it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

You need to disable sip at the el capitan via recovery boot.
Here is more detail:
http://blog.binaryage.com/el-capitan-update/